# <a> with an inner <span> not triggering :active state in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to style the `:active` state of a button that is represented by an `<a>` tag. The `<a>` tag has an inner `<span>` (beacuse I want to add an icon to this button).

I notice the `:active` state is triggered properly in everything but Internet Explorer 8. In IE 8, it appears that the area around the `<span>` (the `<a>`’s padding) triggers the `:active` state, but when clicking directly on the text within the `<span>`, the `:active` state is not triggered.

Is there a way to fix this without resorting to Javascript?

#### HTML

```
<a class="button" href="#">
 <span>Add a link</span>
</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a.button { some styles }
a.button:active { some other styles }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, terribly over-complicated solution (and still imperfect), but: if you don’t wrap the link text in the `<span>`, and instead just use the `<span>` as a place to put your background image and position it absolutely within the `<a>`, then the `<span>` (mostly) stops blocking the `:active` state.

Test page: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/2769392/3/

#### HTML

```
<a class="button" href="#">
<span></span>Link
</a>
```

#### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
a.button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #c00;
}

a.button:active {
    color: #009;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.button span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 3px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    border: solid 2px #000;
}
</style>
```

Of course, the area that the `<span>` covers still traps the click event, so when the user clicks on there, they won’t see the `:active` state. It is a slight improvement on the previous situation.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, Paul. IE never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: This bug was causing me a lot of grief. Thanks for the fix. +1

Comment: @Liam: glad you found it, there’s nothing worse than an obscure and undocumented IE bug.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky: IE 8 doesn’t seem to register the `<a>` tag as active when the `<span>` is clicked. (IE 6 and 7 are both fine. You found a regression!)

It does, however, register the `<span>` tag as active. If you can apply all the styles you want to change for the `:active` state to the `<span>`, then IE 8 will play along, e.g.

```
a.button:active,
a.button span:active/* This selector is for IE 8 only */ {
    color: #009;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Test page: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/2769392/

Any styles that only apply to the link won’t change in IE 8 though. In the example above, the text changes colour when clicked, but the underline does not, as the underline style is attached only to the link (via the browser’s default styles), not the `<span>`.

Comment: Thanks!

Actually, I just tried this in IE8, and the link's style does not change when clicked.

Comment: If you click in the very upper right hand corner of the link, you can get the :active state to trigger, but if you click on the link itself, the :active state does not trigger.

Comment: Aha! IE 8, gotcha. We’ve found a regression, 6 & 7 are both fine. I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that will work with your example.

Unfortunately, the reason I needed to do this in the first place was to manipulate the background property, so your workaround will not work for me.

I guess JavaScript might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and FINALLY figured it out:
You need a target in the `<a>` tag, i.e. add the "href" attribute in the `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="logonButton" class="button submit" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><span>Log On</span></a>
```

Works like a charm in all IE versions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
a.button span { ...
a.button span:hover { ...
```

would work?

Comment: That would work, but I need to change the background-image style of the outer tag (the a tag). The inner tag (the span) needs to have a different background image that doesn't changed based on the hover state.

Comment: @Adam: Then why don't you just not use `a.button span:hover`?

Comment: I'm not applying any :hover styling to the inner span.

The a has <a> background (a gradient), and the <span> has a background (an icon).

When someone clicks the <a>, I want the background to change, but the icon needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could put the `<span>` outside the `<a>` instead. That seems to work.

#### HTML

```
<span><a class="button" href="#">
 Add a link
</a></span>
```

Test page: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/2769392/2/

Comment: Indeed that would work, but the background that needs to change is the one behind the icon, which needs to be applied to the innermost tag.

In this case, I would need the <span> to have an :active state to change the background, and the <a> would have the icon background image.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly same problem today.

Try setting

```
z-index: -1; position: relative;
```

on the span.

This is what i came up with after reading this post.

I actualle wrote a long answer, with example code etc etc etc.. but while indent'ing css code, IE had a choke and crashed..

Comment: yes, it works, but z-index -1 hides span behind anchor, so that if you have background applied to A, all you get is an ampy anchor with nice background :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that fixes the ie8 bug using jquery. Its an unreasonable use of resources for such a minor bug, but the app I was working on a the time was using a lot of jQuery already so it didn't matter.

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Button</span></a>
```

### CSS

```
a.btn:active,
a.btn.ie8:hover { /* <-ie8 hack */
    /* mouse down state a.btn style */
}

a.btn:active span,
a.btn.ie8:hover span { /* <-ie8 hack */
    /* mouse down state a.btn span style */
}
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var isIE8 = ($.browser.msie == true && $.browser.version == "8.0") ? true : false;

    if (isIE8 === true) {
        $("a.btn").bind({
            mousedown: function() {
                $(this).addClass('ie8');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).removeClass('ie8');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using this:

```
$('.yourspan').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parents('.youranchor:first').css("background-position","bottom");   
}); 
$('.yourspan').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).parents('.youranchor:first').css("background-position","top");  
});
```