# Active state on parent element when clicking element

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a button (actually just a link), which design is rather complicated, and as I am optimizing for IE8, can not be made with CSS3. I have therefore placed a `<span>` inside the `<a>`, and put a background image on both.

The image changes on `:hover` and `:active`. It works pretty great in all browsers, but not so much in IE. `:hover` works fine, but when clicking on the `<span>`, the `:active` state of the parent `<a>` is not triggered. It sort of makes sense, but I've seen it work before, so I guess there must be some workaround?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/EtjL3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [<a> with an inner <span> not triggering :active state in IE 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769392/a-with-an-inner-span-not-triggering-active-state-in-ie-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following jQuery to add the css inline on click.

```
              $("a, span").click(function(){
                  $(this).css("background", "green")
                  $(this).find("span").css("background", "lime")    
              });
```

Here's a jsFiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/r5NDw/1/

alternatively you can add classes on click using [addClass();](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Hmm, yes, indeed. Of course, I would have to run it on `mousedown` and `mouseup`, but the problem is still that the button itself is also triggered. I could do that too with Javascript, but it would be too much hacking. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `css class` for the active state using `jquery` or `javascript`.

**Edit**

You can set a css class like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a span").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });     
});
```

and Css Style...

```
a.active { background:green; }
a.active span { background:lime; } ​
```