# Keeping top menu item highlighted while in dropdown

Tags: css, list, drop-down-menu

Just putting together this site and would like the menu item with a dropdown to stay highlighted in white when you are hovering over the dropdown menu items.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7086475/Paul%20Day/index.html

Comment: Ian, thank you so much for leaving your working code in your Dropbox. You saved my bacon today!

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the `#nav a:hover` selector you can use `#nav li:hover` instead.

The li will remain in the hover state while you're in the submenu unlike the anchor.

It won't work in IE6 since the hover pseudo class only works on anchors.

```
#nav li:hover{
 color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `css class` for the hover state of parent li using `jquery or javascript`.

**Edit**

You can set a css class like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li li").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass("test");
    });

    $("#nav li li").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("test");
    });
});
```

and Css Style...

```
.test { font-weight:bold; color:#fff; }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and expand upon this?  And for [the second copy of this answer here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207254)  This isn't really an answer and may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery, it will work to solve your problem

```
$(function() {
        $('#nav li ul').hover(function() {
           $(this).prev('#nav li a').css('color', '#FF6600');
        }, function() {
            $(this).prev('#nav li a').css('color', '#fff');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how do you stop it from staying highlighted once you move off that menu item? Have updated the page.