# Style a a href as a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a large set of HTML components that works in every browser (where did the idea started anyway :-) )

Now, I want to have a button, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466906/remove-3d-push-effect-on-a-button) post on StackOverflow, I should not use a button because that one has a 3D push effect on click. In order to remove that one, the advice was to use a `a href` and style that to the button I like.

So here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Yes</span>
</a>
```

And off course, here's the HTML:

```
a.button {
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
  background-color: #cde6f7;
  border: 1px solid #92c0e0;
}
a:active.button {
  background-color: #92c0e0;
  border: 1px solid #2a8dd4;
}
```

Nothing really commplicated

Now, this does all work in Google Chrome and Firefox as this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hgL3pdm/) demonstrates.

The button has 3 different states:

- A normal 'default' button.
- A style when you hover on it.
- A style when you click on it.

Now, Internet Explorer does not apply a new style when you click on the button, it's the same style as the one on hovering. Unless you click the border (If you manage to click the border, than the correct style does apply).

Now, why do I have this behaviour and can it be solved as it is crucial to the development of my Control Suite.

I know it's possible to solve with jQuery by adding a removing a class when you click on it, but this seems a very ugly solution and if there's a 'CSS-Friendly' solution, I would like to use that one.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769392/a-with-an-inner-span-not-triggering-active-state-in-ie-8. It seems to be due to the inner `<span>` element

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317758/anchor-with-span-dont-apply-active-effect-on-ie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be because the CSS selector is backwards:

Change:

```
a:active.button {
```

to

```
a.button:active {
```

Chrome et al don't appear to give a care about what order these are in, but IE is, well, IE.

```css
a.button {
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
  background-color: #cde6f7;
  border: 1px solid #92c0e0;
}
a.button:active {
  background-color: #92c0e0;
  border: 1px solid #2a8dd4;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Yes</span>
</a>
```

### Edit

The issue appears to be that when you click on the link, you are actually clicking the `span` and, in IE, the click event is not bubbling. As far as IE is concerned, the anchor is not being `:active`ated.

You need to take the `span` out of the anchor:

```css
a.button {
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
  background-color: #cde6f7;
  border: 1px solid #92c0e0;
}
a.button:active {
  background-color: #92c0e0;
  border: 1px solid #2a8dd4;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
    Yes
</a>
```

### Edit

If you need the `span`, then the only solution left is a javascript one.

This block of code adds a mousedown/mouseup event listener to all `.button` elements which toggles the active class on/off.

```
// vanilla JS
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length ; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
        this.classList.add('active');
    }, false);
    anchors[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }, false);
}

// jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a.button').mousedown(
    function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  )
  .mouseup(
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  );
});
```

And we change the `:active` line of the css to:

```
a.button:active,
a.button.active {
  background-color: #92c0e0;
  border: 1px solid #2a8dd4;
}
```

Which listens to both the `:active` pseudo-class, as well as the `.active` class.

```js
//pure JS solution

var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length ; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
        this.classList.add('active');
    }, false);
    anchors[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }, false);
}

//jQuery solution
/*
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a.button').mousedown(
    function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  )
  .mouseup(
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  );
});
*/
```

```css
a.button {
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
  background-color: #cde6f7;
  border: 1px solid #92c0e0;
}
a.button:active,
a.button.active {
  background-color: #92c0e0;
  border: 1px solid #2a8dd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Yes</span>
</a>
```

Comment: lol I love the comment "but IE is, well, IE" . Aint that the ungodly truth?

Comment: The result is the same, it isn't working. Try clicking on the text with IE. The style of the button doesn't change. However, clicking next to the next does trigger the button's style.

Comment: Reminds me of a post where Chrome and Firefox were having an all-out duel, while IE was sucking its thumb.

Comment: I can confirm, this doesn't work for IE either. It seems like the `<span>` is blocking the `:active` behaviour

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0hgL3pdm/9/   even after span is removed the :active class is not set

Comment: @Sai - https://jsfiddle.net/0hgL3pdm/10/ - you need to place the `:active` after the `:hover`.

Comment: @Sai I need the span so this isn't a valid option.

Comment: @Complexity As IE is incapable of doing this right, I'm resorting to javascript to fix this. I've added both vanilla js and jquery solutions to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple problem of priority... `a.button:hover` is more accurate than `a:active.button` so it has precedence. The reason why the browsers don't all behave exactly the same is simply because they handle ties differently.

Making sure that the different pseudo classes are always set at the same level of the selector rule will help counter this problem.

So, this means `a:active.button` should be switched to `a.button:active` or the others be switched...

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle to match what you're saying but the result is still the same. https://jsfiddle.net/0hgL3pdm/6/

Comment: Also, when I do place the active before the hover, clicking on the border also doesn't work which let me think that active is priority over hover. Could you have another look.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove push effect on button by adding a

```
button {
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't answer my question.